# How to cd into a directory with the name "-"?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

I tried to `cd` into a directory named `-` that I created for experimenting. I could not from Bash. How do I cd into it?

With Nautilus on Ubuntu 13.10 I could easily do this, and even create files inside it effortlessly.  I did a Google search and [here](http://linuxers.org/quick-tips/how-open-directory-or-file-starting-hyphen) is what I got. That covers the case when directories *begin* with a `-`, like `-test`, but not the case when the entire name is one single `-`. Even `rm` does not work, although I was able to delete it from Nautilus.

`cat test.txt >-` copies text from `test.txt` into a file named `-`, but `cat - >test2.txt` does what it would do in normal circumstances, that is, copy input from `stdin` into `test2.txt`, not from the file `-`.

Why does Nautilus have no problem with this but bash does?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
cd ./-
```

Or:

```
cd /absolute/path/leading/to/-
```

Or, better:

```
mv ./- something-sensible
cd something-sensible
```

The lone dash is used by a lot of commands to mean 'standard input' or 'standard output'.  A few commands can be persuaded to take one lone dash to standard input and another to mean standard output in a single command invocation: for example, with GNU Tar, `tar -cf - -T -` reads the list of file names to archive from standard input (`-T -`), and writes the tar file to standard output (`-f -`). Such commands never check to see if there is a real file called `-`; they just compare the name with `-` and treat it as the appropriate standard I/O stream.  You work around the problem the same way: use a name such as `./-` to specify the file.

You might also note that a name `--` (double dash) also cause problems because the double dash argument is used to separate options from the file name (non-option) arguments, as in:

```
rm -fr -- -
```

This would remove the file or directory `-`, but would leave the file (or directory) `--` unchanged.  Study the specification of the POSIX [Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) to see where this behaviour is defined.

Comment: The last choice is the best one (+1). :)

Comment: In most systems `cd -` means cd to the last directory you were in. So don't name directories -; or ~, or /, or ., or ..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, one would still expect `cd "-"` to work, but it does not.

Comment: Using `-` as a directory name in the `cd` command is specified by POSIX to be equivalent to: `cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd`. So it does work, just not as you are expecting it to; it returns you to your last working directory.

Comment: @AnkitPati Quoting doesn't help, because they hyphen has no special meaning to the shell parser; it's the `cd` command that assigns it a special meaning.